# HTML - Image Bullet Spacing

Tags: css, html

I am in the middle of a project to update several company intranet sites for HTML5, for IE and Edge.
I need things to look as closely as possible to the old compatibility view.
One item I've really been struggling with is spacing with image bullets and the text to the right of the `<li>`.
I am unable to determine the problem via quirks mode.

Here is how I want them to look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVFbh.jpg

Here is how they currently appear:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEm4G.jpg

And here is a sample of my current CSS:

```
li.BulletExcel {
list-style-image: url('/common/images/bullets/icon_excel2013_16x16.png') !important;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-left: 4px; 
padding-left: 0px;}
li.BulletExcel li {list-style-image: none;}
```

And the default list spacing:

```
UL, OL                               {margin-top: .5em; margin-bottom: .5em;}
UL UL, UL OL, OL UL, OL OL           {margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;}
```

I've played around with both the margin-left and the padding-left, but cannot get the spacing in the "new" as close to the "old" (which is what I want).
The text in the "new" is also migrating down.

This is my first post here, I greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: maybe some white space ... first try `vertical-align: top`. And maybe add some negative magin to li

Comment: Modifying the vertical-align did not change anything. I've tried changing the margin for li to ridiculous numbers, and it will only move so far.